# How do I make HTML5 show validation errors without making user click a submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, submit

I am using ajax to invoke insert and update, so there are insert/update buttons instead of submit buttons (input type="submit"). Actually, I am using AngularJS, but the problem would be the same even if I was just using javaScript/ajax. The problem is that when I execute this javaScript code to programmatically submit the form (see below), HTML5 validation errors are not being shown to the user. HTML5 validation errors seem only to be shown when a submit button is actually clicked (as I saw in may posts and also verified for myself).

```
document.myform.submit();
```

After much effort, I finally found a simple/direct solution that worked for me, so I wanted to share it. What I did was have the insert and the update javaScript functions check the form's validity: if the form is valid, proceed with the ajax call to insert or update; otherwise, trigger the click event on a hidden submit button (input type="submit").

Here is my solution code. If anyone has any suggestions or comments, please let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form  id="personForm" name="personForm">
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" 
                         placeholder="Name" required /> &nbsp;
            Age:
            <input type="number" name="Age" id="Age"  
                         placeholder="Age" required /> &nbsp;

            <input type="button" value="update" onclick="doUpdate();"/>
            <input type="button" value="insert" onclick="doInsert();"/>

            <!-- hidden submit button -->
            <div style="display:none;">
                <input type="submit" id="submitButton"/>
            </div>

            <script>
                function $(element) {
                    return document.getElementById(element);
                }

                function doUpdate() {

                    // if form is invalid...
                    if (!$("personForm").checkValidity()) { 

                        // auto click the submit button which is the only 
                        // way to get html5 show validation errors to user.
                        // Due to errors, it will not actually submit.
                        $("submitButton").click(); 

                     } else {
                        alert("make ajax call for update");
                    }
                }

                function doInsert() {

                    // if form is invalid...
                    if (!$("personForm").checkValidity()) { 

                        // auto click the submit button which is the only 
                        // way to get html5 show validation errors to user.
                        // Due to errors, it will not actually submit.
                        $("submitButton").click(); 

                    } else {
                        alert("make ajax call for insert");
                    }
                }

            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look up the the checkValidity() Method

Comment: You are _not_ using AngularJS at all. All I can see is an original jQuery ID selector emulation that you don't need because 1) you wouldn't be using jQuery's selectors if you used Angular, and 2) Angular already has a built-in jQuery Lite so rewriting the selector is useless anyway.